# What does the -o suffix mean in fontawesome?

Tags: font-awesome

It seems to mean opposite, because it is the inverted version of the non '-o' icon version.

But that doesn't seem like the right answer to me.

There is clearly a pattern behind this decision because many icons follow the same patter.  But what does the '-o' suffix mean?

[image]

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is asking about a design decision about a library.

Comment: i would imagine it means `open`.

Comment: Fair enough I guess, and tbh it's not strictly a programming question. But I like to understand the code I use if possible, and the reason for this naming convention might provide me with insight, however mundane.

Comment: i would ask the developer directly.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

As Daniel suggested I asked Dave Gandy.  If anyone else is curious, it stands for...

[image]